# How to do downloadable file in response from the bot

Tags: node.js, download, botframework, skype

Hello there :)

Challenge Skype; Bot Framework; receive downloadable files

I have an issue. My project is to ask something to the bot (using Bot Framework Emulator currently but later I will use Skype) and the bot answers with an attached image/chart.
I can display through the interface the answer and the image. However, the user cannot download this image.

How can I do that ?
There is an option in an AdaptiveCard message to be able to download the attached image thanks to a Button ?

I tried with HeroCard, ThumbnailCard, AdaptiveCard and a simple attachment but it did not solve my problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways you can go about this.

**Using Cards**

First, cards don't allow you to directly download an attachment. At best, they can link you to the image (or other file) you want your user to download. Example `json` for an Adaptive Card that can do this:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                "url": "https://dev.botframework.com/Client/Images/ChatBot-BotFramework.png"
            },
            "url": "https://dev.botframework.com/Client/Images/ChatBot-BotFramework.png"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This card's action will open an image"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Open Image",
            "url": "https://dev.botframework.com/Client/Images/ChatBot-BotFramework.png"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

And looks like this:

[image: Adaptive Card With Clickable Image]

This card displays an image and includes a link for a user to open and download it. Because I added an `Action.OpenUrl` directly to the image, the user can click the image to open and then download it--the "Open Image" button is just to show another method.

Here's a great website for Adaptive Card [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards), [Schema](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/), and a [user-friendly Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer). Note that the Designer doesn't allow you to easily add `Action`s at this time. You have to manually add them in the `JSON` portion.

**Sending Attachments**

You can, however, directly send a message that includes the ability to download files.

You can define an attachment with:

```
const attachment = {
  name: 'PDF',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
  contentUrl: 'https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/microsoftbotframework/latest/microsoftbotframework.pdf',
}
```

And then send it to the user with:

```
await step.context.sendActivity({
  text: 'Attachment',
  attachments: [attachment],
});
```

Two important notes:

1. This method works well for sending files. If you use an image, it will display an unclickable image. This means Adaptive Cards would be better for sending downloadable images.
2. Your code might use something other than `step.context`. This is for sending it as part of a Waterfall Dialog. You may need some other version of `context.sendActivity` for your bot.

If you found this answered your question, please mark it as "Answered" and I can clear it off of my support ticket tracker. Otherwise, feel free to comment and I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this accurate answer :) However, I see only http links. What about downloading local file ?
I can show a local file by given its canonical path by using : __dirname+"/myImg.png". I can also download it by given the same canonical path too in "url" parameter. However, when the Action.OpenUrl is triggered, is it launched locally where the botFramework is installed OR is it launched locally where the nodejs SDK is running ?